# Parametrized remaining seconds until next interval

Tags: c#

I wanted to return the remaining time until the next interval (KlineInterval). Basically, I want to avoid hard-coding stuff. My code works fine for 1-hour interval but it doesn't support the rest of the intervals. I want it to support all of them and if there is a way to do that in a not hard-coded way (those ugly  `if`s).

Is this possible?

```
public enum KlineInterval
{
    OneMinute = 0,
    ThreeMinutes = 1,
    FiveMinutes = 2,
    FifteenMinutes = 3,
    ThirtyMinutes = 4,
    OneHour = 5,
    TwoHour = 6,
    FourHour = 7,
    SixHour = 8,
    EightHour = 9,
    TwelveHour = 10,
    OneDay = 11,
    ThreeDay = 12,
    OneWeek = 13,
    OneMonth = 14
}

public static double RemainingSecondsUntilNextInterval(KlineInterval interval)
{
    if (interval == KlineInterval.FiveMinutes)
    {
        double currentTimeUnixTimestamp = DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(DateTime.Now);
        int minutesInSeconds = 5 * 60;
        return minutesInSeconds - (currentTimeUnixTimestamp % minutesInSeconds);
    }
    else if (interval == KlineInterval.OneHour)
    {
        var timeOfDay = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        var nextFullHour = TimeSpan.FromHours(Math.Ceiling(timeOfDay.TotalHours));
        return (nextFullHour - timeOfDay).TotalSeconds;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Interval not supported.");
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    private static double DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return (TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTime) -
               new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalSeconds;
    }

    private static double RemainingSecondsUntilXMinutes(int minutes)
    {
        double currentTimeUnixTimestamp = DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(DateTime.Now);
        return (minutes * 60) - (currentTimeUnixTimestamp % (minutes * 60));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Remaining seconds until the next hour
        var nextHour = RemainingSecondsUntilXMinutes(60);

        // Remaining seconds until the next 5 minutes
        var nextFiveMinutes = RemainingSecondsUntilXMinutes(5);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

@Max, is that what you wanted to say?

Comment: Side Note: Don't ToString your enums.  Just use the value.  `if (interval == KlineInterval.FiveMinutes)`

Comment: This is kinda hacky but you could make your enum int values equal to the number of minutes each span of time represents, then do math with that value. For example, `KlineInterval.OneHour = 60`

Comment: @LarsTech, that's true. I was thinking about something working for all minutes, then all hours, then all days, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to be aware of the fact that there will need to be some place where each of the enums you have declared are mapped to their expected behaviour. (There is also the option of parsing the string values of the enums. This is very hacky and I would advise against it.) This means that you will need to have some control flow that splits based on the enum type. You can do this with either an if statement or a switch statement (switch statements are more common for this purpose, but both work fine).

Still, it's not necessary to have 3 lines of code within each branch. You can bring it down to just one line per branch. When trying to reduce the amount of code duplication, it is helpful to look at which parts are the same in the different cases and which are different.

In this case, it's useful to first convert the enum into a `Timespan` and then implement some logic based on this `Timespan` that computes the number of remaining seconds. One method could deal with converting the enum to a `Timespan`, and the other could calculate the remaining seconds in the interval based on the `Timespan`, like so:

```cs
private static double RemainingSecondsUntilNextInterval(Timespan interval) {
// ...
}
private static Timespan TimespanFromKlineInterval(KlineInterval interval) {
    switch(interval){
       case KlineInterval.OneMinute:
// ...
}
public static double RemainingSecondsUntilNextInterval(KlineInterval interval) {
    return RemainingSecondsUntilNextInterval(TimespanFromKlineInterval(interval));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's acceptable solution. What about calculating the difference for minutes, days and weeks based on `TimeSpan`. Like, I know how to do it only for hours?

Comment: For seconds, minutes, hours, days and weeks, you can use the same code: convert the current time to a UNIX timestamp and take the remainder (`%` operator) on division by the total amount of seconds in the unix timestamp (this works because UNIX timestamps have no support for leap seconds). The month would be trickier though because not every month is the same size. You'll need a separate way of handling months.